# JavaScript code like TextArea Wrapping or Div overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on HTML5 project. I want to wrap my text inside a rectangle(i.e. boundary for text) on a HTML5 canvas. I want to wrap text similar to that of a `<textarea>`. When I resize the textarea the text should get resized itself (w.r.t. line or Characters). This is what I want: To wrap text when I resize a rectangle on a HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Try mentioning the `<canvas/>` in your question for completeness.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not just use an HTML element that has the functionality already built in and position over the `canvas`?  I can't see any benefit to recreating functionality that's already available.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/01/20/creating-a-user-resizable-div-tag-using-css3/

If so, you need to set an `overflow` property as explained.

**EDIT :**

As you seem to be using `<canvas>`, you can take a look at this tutorial explaining how to wrap text in a canvas with javascript within a specific context :

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for answer.I am not using div. i am using Canvas. and i have also mentioned that i need javascript code not CSS.

Comment: I have used this script for wrapping text, but it only wraps line not characters.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific or put up a little jsFiddle to show what you've done or what you mean?